# Setting up a new server with xen / proxmox virtualization and multiple subdomains

Tags: php, apache, subdomain, virtualization

I am running a server with an old version of Debian, which needs to be upgraded. To do this, I want to replace this server with a new one, run both simultaneously, set up the new one and replace the old.

The old server is running Apache 2 for our forums, website, wiki etc. with PHP 5 and MySQL (and each with one subdomain e.g. forum.XXX.com, wiki.XXX.com etc). PHP 5 is "needed" because we got some legacy stuff that does not work on new versions of php (yet).

I thought about using PHP 5 and PHP 7, because as mentioned we need PHP 5 but we want to use some features for the new stuff, which requires PHP 7. With this in mind and the ability to e.g. update the server and still have the forums available, I thought about virtualization. But as far as i know, we only have 1 IP address.

Is this a "good" idea, or are there alternatives much better? My goal is to get the new server running with PHP 7 if possible. If not, I will stick with PHP 5 (on Debian 9?).

I am open for your suggestions and help for the idea mentioned above.

Comment: You could create Docker images for each of your apps, and proxy requests from your port 80/443 traffic to the relevant container. Apache can do this, but Traefik would be better. Each app can have its own version of PHP. However, it depends on whether your old server can run a modern version of Docker - might be a good idea to put a small VPS in front of it that does the routing.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answers. Yes, i mean newer.
I have not worked with either Docker or Traefik, but i could try them both. Need to read some tutorials about it first, though.

Comment: I found the possibility to run an nginx server with multple versions auf PHP. this would be the easiest solution, right? what is the downside of it, compared to e.g. proxmox virtualization or Docker images? And what would you suggest, and why?

Comment: Yes, if you can run NginX with multiple versions of PHP, that is easiest. I like Docker because I know it already, because I'm already using it for security isolation in production, and because it minimises environmental differences as a version is promoted through various stages towards production. It is a lot more work though.

Comment: The docs for Docker are excellent, but you can expect something of a learning curve, since there are a number of pitfalls with it, as with any unfamiliar technology. I thoroughly recommend it to any software engineer, but it is best learned prior to needing it, unless your current need is not urgent.

Comment: How would the Docker Setup look like, having multiple subdomains, 2 different php versions (for website NEW and OLD) and databases for each subdomain? The new server should be able to run Docker, so each App (so each "website" or "service"?) would get a new container ?

Comment: Yes, one container per site, and one container for the frontend proxy (Apache/Traefik) though you can do the latter on the host if you prefer. I have [blogged about this](https://blog.jondh.me.uk/2018/04/dockerising-simple-vps-machines/). You can see the process of building one `Dockerfile`, you need one of these per container (this one is quite complex, but they tend to start off much simpler!).

Comment: The subdomains config goes in Apache/Traefik, and does not affect the app containers. As far as they are concerned, they just listen to port 80, even if you're using SSL before the proxy stage.